Reading List of Json Objects from Json File with S3 source in airbyte gives parsing error
So, i am trying to move data from s3 folder to postgres database via airbyte which was working very well with all the configuration about connection setup.
But, now i have came across the situation where new type of json file have arrived which have list of json objects in them like

["key1":"value1", "key2:"value2"]

i just want them to be loaded in under single column via airbyte and i can parse them using dbt later on.
But the issue is, the default schemaless behavior of airbyte is `

{"data":"object"}

`
which leads to the issue of my json file having list of json object not single object.
And if i try to use the airbyte infer schema , it gives me file configuration error.
Have anyone faced this same issue ???
